# Training nltk tagger with Indian POS data

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am trying to train nltk trainer with indian corpus. I mainly targetting `telugu.pos`

I followed http://nltk-trainer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/train_tagger.html and trained. Here is the snapshot[image]

When I tried to test it with telugu text. `నా పేరు కరీం ఉంది. నేను భారత ఆహార ప్రేమ.` which is in English `My name is Karim. I love Indian food.`. It gives this error.

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Am I doning somethign wrong?

[image]

Edit

I edited the text

```
sent = "నా పేరు కరీం ఉంది. నేను భారత ఆహార ప్రేమ.".decode('utf-8')
```

Now it gives result like

```
>>> text = nltk.word_tokenize(sent)
>>> text
[u'\u0c28\u0c3e', u'\u0c2a\u0c47\u0c30\u0c41', u'\u0c15\u0c30\u0c40\u0c02', u'\u0c09\u0c02\u0c26\u0c3f', u'.', u'\u0c28\u0c47\u0c28\u0c41', u'\u0c2d\u0c3e\u0c30\u0c24', u'\u0c06\u0c39\u0c3e\u0c30', u'\u0c2a\u0c4d\u0c30\u0c47\u0c2e', u'.']
>>> nltk.pos_tag(text)
[(u'\u0c28\u0c3e', 'JJ'), (u'\u0c2a\u0c47\u0c30\u0c41', 'NNP'), (u'\u0c15\u0c30\u0c40\u0c02', 'NNP'), (u'\u0c09\u0c02\u0c26\u0c3f', 'NNP'), (u'.', '.'), (u'\u0c28\u0c47\u0c28\u0c41', 'VB'), (u'\u0c2d\u0c3e\u0c30\u0c24', 'JJ'), (u'\u0c06\u0c39\u0c3e\u0c30', 'NNP'), (u'\u0c2a\u0c4d\u0c30\u0c47\u0c2e', 'NNP'), (u'.', '.')]
```

How can I print this content into original language?

Comment: it seems like Wiktor Stribiżew is right, try to change your terminal $LANG to utf-8

Comment: Thanks it helped.  I updated my question. Still problem persist in result. I appreciate your help. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Encode each result as UTF8. Play with `.encode()`/`decode()` to see the difference.

Comment: Something like `s =  nltk.pos_tag(text)` and `print([(x.encode('utf-8'), y) for x,y in s])`